# Running a PHP script at a specific place in the code

Tags: php, html, database

Ok, So I have a external php script that get data from a DB and displays it in a table. I want to run it in a specific div in my html so the data gets echoed out in the right place?

Any ideas how to do that?

Html div

```
<div id="statsContent">

<?php include('updatestats.php'); ?>

</div>
```

Heres the PHP code.

```
<?php

//Start session
session_start();

//Make sure user is logged in
require_once('auth.php');

//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Connect to DB
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
die("Unable to select database");
}

//Create Querys
$query = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE member_id='" . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "' "; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

//Gather the whole row into an array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    $money = $row['money'];
    $bank_money = $row['bank_money'];
    $ap = $row['ap'];
    $exp = $row['exp']; 
} 

//Now create a table to display the data to the user
echo "<table> 
<tr>
    <td>Money $$money</td>
    <td>Action Points $ap</td>
    <td>Experience $exp</td>
</tr>";

?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'run it in a specific div'?

Comment: well i have a grey box that i want to table in. The content for the box is inside a div.

Comment: It's just a question of including / echoing in the appropriate places w the appropriate HTML, CSS, PHP.... hence some example input / desired output would be super helpful.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Why don't you simply put the PHP code where you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just include it inside your div by using:

```
<?php include('filename.php'); ?>
```

Comment: The grey box just dissapears and none of the content is display.

Comment: Ill add the php page in my OP.

Comment: oh wow. i didnt close the table tag and it f-ed everything else up.

problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

you can include PHP script in any tag by calling 
`include("path_to/myscript.php")` or `require("path_to/myscript.php")`

```
  <div>
<?php include("path_to/myscript.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I can't edit this for you, but for clarifcation, "or" is not part of the code above. It is either        include("path_to/myscript.php")       
or       
require("path_to/myscript.php")         
but not both.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div><?php *whatever you want to do inside the div*?></div>
```